# Change background body images with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new at javascript and jQuery and I want to use one of those to change my background body images with onclick. Exactly what I want is to create a link with an image so when the people click on it the background body pic will change. Can you help me or give me a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="set-background"><img src="/path/to/image.jpg">Select Image</a>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.set-background', function(){
    $('body').css({
        'background' : 'url(' + $(this).find('img').attr('src') + ')'
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button>Change background</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $('body').css('background-image','image.jpg');
});
```